# In Gedit, how might I jump from the command line (bottom frame) to the file explorer frame to the text editor frame using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gedit

I know how to jump from tab to tab in the text editor frame, but jumping from the text editor (center-right top frame) to the command line (center-right bottom frame) using only the keyboard eludes me.

I know that jumping straight out of the command line frame probably won't be possible (or as easy as jumping out of one of the other two frames), but knowing how to do the other jumps would save me (and stackexchange posterity) a fair amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

The following shortcuts work on my system (`gnome/gEdit 3.18`):

- From file-browser to terminal: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- From file-browser to text-editor: <kbd>F6</kbd>
- From text-editor to file-browser: <kbd>F6</kbd> two times
- From terminal to text-editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> three times

I've noticed that these work just fine as long as I'm using only the keyboard to navigate. If I start using the mouse too then using `F6` from the text editor will sometimes switch to the embedded terminal.

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 (gedit 3.18 too):  File-browser (side panel) to editor: : `tab`, from editor to terminal: `Ctrl` + `Tab` or  or `F6`; from terminal to editor: `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `Tab`.

Answer (score 1):

I can do the following:

Text-Editor to File Browser:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> followed by 6 x <kbd>Tab</kbd> (does somebody know an easier way here?)

File Browser to Text-Editor:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> 2x <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way I found to switch between the embedded terminal and the text-editor:

From the embedded terminal to the text-editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> three times (as don_crissti mentioned)

From the text-editor back to the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> three times

Update: 
Weirdly, It seems to work when gedit has only one tab open.

Answer (score -1):

gEdit 3.36.2 on Linux Mint 20.1:

```
    From browser to terminal    Tab
    From browser to editor      F6
    From editor to browser      F6 x 2
    From editor to terminal     Ctrl+Tab+(Up Arrow x 2)  or  Ctrl+Shift+Tab x 3
    From terminal to editor     Ctrl+Tab x 3
    From terminal to browser    Ctrl+Shift+Tab
```

Comment: This hints have already been given above, with more effort regarding formatting and context. You should check if you have something new to contribute, and for a helpful answer you are expected to do a bit more than just copy/pasting. Please also take the [tour] and read [answer].